# On how to formulate and apply maximum likelihood

Tags: estimation, matlab, maximum-likelihood

I have just delved into the basics of maximum likelihood estimation and expectation maximization. The latter is really difficult to follow and I am having a tough time in figuring how I can apply the EM method for parameter estimation.

Comment: "ML" is not an algorithm but a criterion. MLE doesn't find a minimum, it's the value of (a monotonic function) of the thing you try to optimize. Minimizing $J$ probably\* *is* ML (in that its argmin will correspond to ML. \*(I haven't done more than taken a quick glance at the paper, but you should have at least mentioned you were doing some form of nearest-neighbor modelling here, and better still you should write more details of your model in your question.)

Comment: I have added the nearest neighbor point, my mistake sorry for that. So, the thing is EM solution for minimizing the objective function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use EM to obtain maximum likelihood estimates, you need a variable that describes your observations $x_{n}$, latent variables $z_{n}$ that are in some way related to your observations (e.g. in coin tossing experiments, $\{H, T\}$ are the latent variables and in gaussian mixtures, the mixing coefficients $\pi_{i}$ take the role of latent variables) and the parameters $\theta$ that you are trying to estimate.

At the risk of not answering your question at all, I think you want a maximum likelihood estimate of $\theta$ using EM based on known observations $x_{n}$ that are given by the following equation:

$$x_{t} = s_{t}(\theta_{0}) + n_{t}$$

If that is correct, a general idea is the following. Since $n_{t}$ is white noise $N(0, \sigma)$, $x_{t}$ can be described by a Gaussian $p(x_{t}|s_{t},\theta) = N(s_{t}(\theta), \sigma)$. In the EM formulation, $x_{t}$'s are known variables, $s_{t}$'s are latent variables and $\theta$ is the parameter. It is customary to group the variables $x_{n}$ in a variable $X$ and likewise, latent variables $s_{n}$ are grouped in a variable $S$.

As you should know, the EM algorithm consists of 2 steps: expectation and maximization. In the expectation step, we use an expression $Q$ as a proxy for the likelihood $L(\theta|X) = p(X|\theta)$, that is, the probability of 
getting the known data $X$ given a parameter $\theta$. This is the same likelihood used to obtain maximum likelihood estimates. However, in EM we use this $Q$ instead:

$$Q(\theta|\theta^{\text{old}}) = E_{S|X, \theta^{\text{old}}} \log p(X,S|\theta)$$

This odd-looking expression is actually a lower bound of the likelihood $L(\theta|X)$. [Bishop's book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387310738) contains a good derivation of $Q$.

In order to start the EM magic, you have to choose a random $\theta^{\text{old}}$ and calculate this expectation. Notice that you need $p(X,S|\theta)$ and $p(S|X,\theta^{\text{old}})$. $p(X,S|\theta)$ is equal to $p(X|S,\theta)p(S|\theta)$ and using Bayes' theorem, $p(S|X,\theta^{\text{old}})$ is 
proportional to $p(X|S,\theta^{\text{old}})p(S|\theta^{\text{old}})$.

At this point, I hope it is clear that $p(X|S,\theta)=\prod_{t} p(x_{t}|s_{t},\theta)$, so that part is not hard to calculate. However, $p(S|\theta)$, that is, $\prod_{t}p(s_{t}|\theta)$ is required. I don't know what distribution could be appropriate since this depends on the specifics of your problem so I will assume you know.

By now, you can calculate $Q(\theta|\theta^{\text{old}})$.

The maximization step is simply:

$$\theta = \text{arg max}_{\theta} Q(\theta|\theta^{\text{old}})$$

This is the new $\theta$ to be used in the expectation step again until convergence.

That is a general idea of how EM could work in this case. However, maybe you don't know a distribution for $s_{t}$ or it is difficult to calculate the expectation or the maximization step.

For the big picture, take a look at [this](https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http://www.nature.com/nbt/journal/v26/n8/pdf/nbt1406.pdf) nice explanation.

**UPDATE**

I think you changed the question quite a bit. Are you asking how to calculate maximum likelihood estimates? Basically, you apply a derivative to the likelihood on the parameter you want to estimate:

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}L(\theta|X) = 0$$

solve it and that's pretty much it. See more examples [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_likelihood#Continuous_distribution.2C_continuous_parameter_space).

Comment: Thank you for a good general introduction. My question was I have observations u whose distribution is gaussian. I need to minimize/optimize using ML and EM.In my case u's are higher dimensional signal which has the parameters embedded in it.I need to formulate u's so that I can apply EM.Assuming u's follow a Gaussian distribution & u is a 2*N dimensional signal where N represents no.of samples.How do I formulate since I cannot do a derivative of u's?Is it possbile to find the parameters assuming gaussian distribution and unknown signal generating model?

Comment: If you can't solve the ML because the derivatives are too complicated, then EM is a good alternative. If $u$'s are observations and follow a gaussian distribution, then you need to include latent variables in that distribution. For example, what is the probability of a signal $u_{t}$ given some other variable $z_{t}$ provided you can calculate $p(z_{t}|\theta)$. If you can do that, follow the procedure I described and it will give you an estimate of $\theta$.

Comment: Is the process similar to EM of gaussian mixture models and its implementation http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/26184-em-algorithm-for-gaussian-mixture-model. In my case what is z_t?After I find out the distribution how do I find the probability?By this time u must have know that I am really weak in this area.From your procedure which steps should I follow to minimize u_t using EM?It will be really nice if you can edit your answer adding how to apply EM on u's such that u's can be minimized.

Comment: This process is exactly the same as in mixture models. $z_{t}$ depends on your problem. As I said, in mixture models $z_{t}$ are the mixture coefficients, so it's quite easy to define a joint distribution $p(X,Z|\theta)$. Obviously, I don't know the dependencies of your observations $u_{t}$, that is something you should know, but basically the idea is to find such joint distribution. Furthermore, in EM you don't minimize $u$. Instead, maximize the likelihood of  $p(U|\theta)$ using $Q$ as a proxy. I recommend you to read chapter 9 of Bishop's book.

Comment: So for my case it will theta=arg max E [log p(U|theta)] ?This means the probability of u's given theta, but I do not know theta as I need to estimate theta ! Also, will this formulation give me multiple parameters theta_1, theta_2 etc as my model has multiple parameters to be estimated.

Comment: In your case, $E[\log p(U,Z|\theta)]$. Remember that this is a recursive procedure, so you start by guessing $\theta$. After several iterations, the estimate for $\theta$ will converge to the ML estimate. As for your second question, yes. In the same way $X$ represents the set of observations, $\theta$ represents a set of parameters, although in this case I assumed there was only one parameter to be estimated.

Comment: Is there any implementation for this kind of thing or do I follow the matlab link for implementation?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11008/discussion-between-srishti-m-and-robert-smith)

Comment: Lastly, in some papers I have read that if the objective is to minimize then I take the negative of the log likelihood, apply kalman filters. Is this correct? Do I need to apply kalman filter? Or as u said maximizing the probability yields the parameters. thank you so much for continued help